# New to java; how do I make the String static within conditionals?

Tags: java, static

```
public class testing {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     boolean a = true;
     if (a) {
       public static String word = " ";
     }
     else if (a == false) {
       public static String word = "not";
     }
     System.out.println(word);
   }
   
 }
```

Instead of printing the value, it tells me "Illegal modifier for the variable word; only final is permitted.
I tried to use `public static final String word = "not";`
but I still got an error saying that it is wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to make the variable `static`? This makes no sense here (besides the other issues in the code).

Comment: `public` and `static` are only for member variables of a class, not for local variables (= variables defined inside a method).

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be created outside of your `main`:

```java
public class Testing {

   public static String word;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     boolean a = true;
     if (a) {
       word = " ";
     } else {
       word = "not";
     }
     System.out.println(word);
   }
   
 }
```

Alternatively you can create a variable inside you `main` as well.

```java
public class Testing {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     boolean a = true;
     String word;
     if (a) {
       word = " ";
     } else {
       word = "not";
     }
     System.out.println(word);
   }
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When variables, blocks or methods are made *static*, they are made available during load time. Rest all reserves memory during run time. All the local variables created inside a static method are present in the method stack, which as a package is already present during load time. So creating a static variable inside method, be it be static or non-static method, is not allowed.